# Is there a good script/program for MySQL raw backups?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, backup

Any recommandation for MySQL raw backups scripts or programs. I was looking for simple script that does pull backups from external site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I use [automysqlbackup](http://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/). It seems to work great for my needs. I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "...script that does pull backups from external site." Could you clarify?

Comment: The script runs on remote server instead of the server the web is hosted on.

Comment: Sure - you can point automysqlbackup at whatever host you'd like. Keep in mind that the backup server will need to be able to contact the target server on port 3306/tcp (or whatever other port you have mysql configured to listen on).

Comment: You're welcome. You're new here, so I'll give you a hint - please accept answers that you're satisfied with. If you don't do this, people will be much less likely to answer your questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

try the community version of MySQL-ZRM
[link text](http://www.zmanda.com/backup-mysql.html)

I have had good luck with it.